# Factory method reference confusion, and guideline to code it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coding-style, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have following angular service.

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("theModule")
      .factory("theService", theServiceFactory);

    function theServiceFactory() {

      return {
          theFn: theFn,
          theFailureFn: theFailureFn,
          theSuccessFn: theSuccessFn
      };

      function theFn() {
          angular.noop();
      }

      function theFailureFn() {
          theFn();
      }

      function theSuccessFn() {
        this.theFn();
      }

    }

}());
```

Functions are defined separately and their references are assigned to object being returned by the factory.

And I have following jasmine test cases.

```
describe("The Service Test Specifications", function () {

    var theService;

    beforeEach(module('theModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_theService_) {
        theService = _theService_;
    }));

    it("should call 'theFn' from 'theFailureFn'", function () {
        spyOn(theService, "theFn");
        theService.theFailureFn();
        expect(theService.theFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it("should call 'theFn' from 'theSuccessFn'", function () {
        spyOn(theService, "theFn");
        theService.theSuccessFn();
        expect(theService.theFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Test Case `should call 'theFn' from 'theFailure'` is being failed whereas `should call 'theFn' from 'theSuccess'` is being passed.

From source code it seems `object's theFn` is referring to `function theFn` but actually it's not. It is causing first test case to fail. **(Q1) At what stage different reference is assigned to `object's theFn`?**

Second test case is passing as `theFn` is invoked with `this` inside `theSuccess`. But using `this` in that situation is strict mode violation. I like and follow [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) so I created `factory` and defined all functions below it. **(Q2) What would be the better way to write such function?**

**(Q3) If `theFailure` is written correctly, is there any way to detect in test case that `function theFn` is called?**

---

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/PsQTZQlIgWI3OTMaYi7n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually calling `theFn()` from `theFailureFn()`, and NOT calling `theFn()` from the `sucesssFn()`. It's the opposite result of your test.

As you see from this,

http://plnkr.co/edit/Tp5FtsL8DAjkcPO0m0ZV?p=preview

```
  console.log('theService.theFn BEFORE spyOn', theService.theFn);
  spyOn(theService, "theFn");
  console.log('theService.theFn AFTER spyOn', theService.theFn);
```

Result

```
  theService.theFn BEFORE spyOn theFn()
  theService.theFn AFTER  spyOn j$.createSpy.spy()
```

your Jasmine `spyOn(theService, "theFn");` is setting an instance of theService, `this.theFn`, and your test is checking `this.theFn` is called or not. Remember that `theService` is a Hash, not a function.

As you see from the output of this line;

```
    console.log('caller theFailureFn', this, theFn, this.theFn)
    //OUTPUT
    caller theFailureFn Object {} theFn() j$.createSpy.spy()
```

`theFn` and `this.theFn` is very different. `theFn` is an object property value and `this.theFn` is an instance of object, Hash.

To answer your question,

**(Q1) At what stage different reference is assigned to object's theFn**
`theFn` is assigned as you expected. `spyOn` makkes difference in your case.

**(Q2) What would be the better way to write such function?**
To test a function calls a function of an object, it should return a function, not a hash.

**(Q3) If theFailure is written correctly, is there any way to detect in test case that function theFn is called?**
The same answer as Q2.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer. Now I have no doubts related to Q1. But I am not able to fully understand your answer of Q2. Could you please explain it with example?

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `this` in `.factory()`. Factory is just executed as function and it just returns what you explicitly specify as return object. Angular uses `.service()` as a constructor function which is executed  with `new` operator and thats the place where you will use `this`.

That means that your `theFailureFn()` is written correctly.

As for Q3, it may fail just because how spyOn is implemented.

Edit:

As i supposed, its the implementation of `spyOn()`.

spyOn wraps the function but in your factory you are still referencing the original function. Try to use `expect(this.theFn).toHaveBeenCalled();`